# GraphViz - generate graph on top of assorted list of nodes/edges with python?

Tags: python, graph, graphviz, pygraphviz

I have a list of items that relate to each other, I know they end up building a graph but the data is not sorted in any way.

```
PMO-100 -> SA-300
SA-100 -> SA-300
SA-100 -> SA-200
PMO-100 -> SA-100
```

In python examples for graphViz api I realize that you can pretty much generate a graph if you know it's top node and can run down the levels and build all the relations.

Since I'm getting an assorted list (I only know that it is a graph since all relations are figured from a single point) - is there a way to build a graph on top of this data?

**Update:** the first comment to this question identifies I haven't correctly explained what I'm after. Indeed the following code gets you a proper graph:

```
gr = pydot.Dot(graph_type='digraph')
    for link in graph.links:
        edge = pydot.Edge(link.outwardIssue.key, link.inwardIssue.key)
        gr.add_edge(edge)
    gr.write('graph.png',format='png')
```

my question really is - how can I color-rode individual nodes or change type of arrow for a specific edge?

Comment: Sure, just add all those edges you have to the graph and let graphviz sort it all out. Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to change color of nodes:

node.attr["color"] = 'red'

to change the shape of arrowhead, same method

edge.attr["arrowhead"] = "..."

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to identify a top node for graphviz. Just add all Nodes and edges and let it do the rest. For example:

```
import pydot
graph = pydot.Dot('graphname', graph_type='digraph') 
pmo100 = pydot.Node("PMO-100")
sa300 = pydot.Node("SA-300")
sa100 = pydot.Node("SA-100")
sa200 = pydot.Node("SA-200")
graph.add_edge(pydot.Edge(pmo100, sa300))
graph.add_edge(pydot.Edge(sa100, sa300))
graph.add_edge(pydot.Edge(sa100, sa200))
graph.add_edge(pydot.Edge(pmo100, sa100))
graph.write_png('example1_graph.png')
```

This will result in the following image:

[image: result]

You can find more info at http://pythonhaven.wordpress.com/2009/12/09/generating_graphs_with_pydot/

Answer (score 0):

Try out [pygraph](http://github.com/iamaziz/pygraph) package, it produces a directed graph based on relation statements (data). No matter if the data are sorted or not.

So (as in your case) if we have the following data (in a triple relation), it is easy to produce the corresponding graph:

#### First way

```
s1 = "PMO-100 -> SA-300"
s2 = "SA-100 -> SA-300"
s3 = "SA-100 -> SA-200"
s4 = "PMO-100 -> SA-100"

from pygraph.dgraph import PyGraph

g = PyGraph()

g.add_relation(s1)
g.add_relation(s2)
g.add_relation(s3)
g.add_relation(s4)

g.draw_graph(label=False)
```

It will produce:

[image]

Or you can even read the relations from a file.

#### Second way

Say, you have `data.txt`:

```
PMO-100 -> SA-300
SA-100 -> SA-300
SA-100 -> SA-200
PMO-100 -> SA-100
```

It is even easier in 4 loc,:

```
from pygraph.dgraph import PyGraph

g = PyGraph()

g.file_relations("data.txt")

g.draw_graph(label=False)
```

In both ways the result is the same:

[image]